# Trying to arrange SQL query to properly use DATEDIFF()

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm creating a query where I'm showing the different statuses a member has had, and how long they were in each status.

This is what I've written so far:

```
    select memberid, 
    case when statusname = "Pending" then cast(statusdate as date) end as StatusDate1,
    case when statusname ="In Progress" then cast(statusdate as date) end as StatusDate2, 
    case when statusname = "Approved" then cast(statusdate as date) end as StatusDate3
    into #test
    from Table A
    group by memberid, case when statusname = "Pending" then cast(statusdate as date) end, 
    case when statusname ="In Progress" then cast(statusdate as date) end,
    case when statusname = "Approved" then cast(statusdate as date) end
```

This produces this result:

```
     Member Id     StatusDate1  StatusDate2 StatusDate3 
     10          2017-01-06      null         null             
     10            null       2017-02-20      null
     10            null          null         2017-03-02
```

I then tried using a DATEDIFF to get the length of time between statuses:

```
    select *, DATEDIFF(dd, StatusDate2, StatusDate1) as Length1
    from #test
```

But this didn't work as it just gave me a null.  I'm thinking the issue is that the status dates all need to be on one line.  I tried doing a UNION where the first query only had StatusDate 1, the next UNION had StatusDate2, but it still didn't put them on one line.

Any suggestions on how to get the number of days between status dates?

Comment: Use aggregation around each case.. For example `MAX(case when...end) as StatusDate1`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post some sample data so that we can see what lies behind your query.

Comment: Is a single member guaranteed to be in each status only once?

Comment: Mureinik--yes, I believe a single member should only be in each status only once.

Answer (score 2):

Complete the pivot on each member by aggregating over `memberid`:

```
SELECT
    memberid,
    MAX(CASE WHEN statusname = 'Pending'
             THEN CAST(statusdate AS DATE) END) AS StatusDate1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN statusname = 'In Progress'
             THEN CAST(statusdate AS DATE) END) AS StatusDate2, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN statusname = 'Approved'
             THEN CAST(statusdate AS DATE) END) AS StatusDate3
INTO #test
FROM TableA
GROUP BY memberid
```

Comment: I am using a group, just forgot to put it on the original query.  I'll update that now.

Comment: @jackstraw22 The important part here is the `MAX()`.. try this instead of your current query.

Comment: I just tried the MAX() but it's still putting all the dates on separate lines.

Comment: @jackstraw22 Look at your current `GROUP BY`.  You are grouping by `memberid` and by each case expression.  This can't be right.  Aggregate _only_ by the `memberid`.

Comment: When using the MAX() I removed the Case expressions from the Group By.  It's now only grouping by the non-aggregated fields.  But it's still putting them on different lines.

Comment: I see.  It works when I remove all the other fields(which I didn't show in the query).  I'll have to play with this to get this to work with additional fields.

Answer (score 0):

use this query before applying your second query

```
select memberid, max(statusDate1) statusDate1, max(statusDate2) statusDate2, 
max(statusDate3) statusDate3
from
(
select memberid, 
    case when statusname = "Pending" then cast(statusdate as date) end as StatusDate1,
    case when statusname ="In Progress" then cast(statusdate as date) end as StatusDate2, 
    case when statusname = "Approved" then cast(statusdate as date) end as StatusDate3
    into #test
    from Table A
    group by memberid, case when statusname = "Pending" then cast(statusdate as date) end, 
    case when statusname ="In Progress" then cast(statusdate as date) end,
    case when statusname = "Approved" then cast(statusdate as date) end 
)
group by memberid
```