# A better way to write a Case statement in DATEDIFF()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, datediff

I've written a query that finds the number of days a record has been in a particular status.  I've got the query working correctly, but I just want to know if there's a more efficient way of writing this.  My starting data looks like this:

```
   MemberID StatusDate1   StatusDate2   StatusDate3   StatusDate4
     77         2017-01-06    2017-03-30     NULL         2017-04-13
     88         NULL          NULL           2017-07-19   NULL
```

The end result looks like this:

```
   MemberID  StatusDate1   StatusDate2   StatusDate3   StatusDate4
     77         83             14            NULL          116
     88        NULL            NULL            19          NULL
```

The issue is if there's a NULL Status Date then I need to find the next populated date and use that.  I'm using a Case statement for the calculation, and while it does work, I keep thinking there has to be a better way than how I've written it:

```
    Select *, DATEDIFF(dd, StatusDate1, case when StatusDate2 is not null then StatusDate2,
                                             when StatusDate2 is null then StatusDate3,
                                             when StatusDate3 is not null then StatusDate3,
                                             when StatusDate3 is null then StatusDate4,
                                             when StatusDate4 is null then getdate())end) as NewStatusDate1
```

I'm writing this for all 4 Status Dates.  Is there a simpler way to write this?

Comment: Note that one of your first two cases must be true, so none of the next 3 will ever execute. If you want to use the first non-null value between those three fields then Gordon;s answer is correct.

Comment: Looking and this question and the [previous you asked 2 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551152/trying-to-arrange-sql-query-to-properly-use-datediff), I think your approach might be wrong from the start. Why don't you go back and show the original table before #test and explain what you are trying as whole, not by parts. Maybe it will be better to first find how much time has each status lasted before doing pivoting.

Comment: FYI - your current logic will not get past checking StatusDate2 and there are no commas in a case statement.

Comment: @Keith--that was just a typo when I typed it in here.  My actual query doesn't have that.

Comment: But still if you check is StatusDate2 is not null and then if it is null then one of those 2 will be true. So your logic will either use StatusDate2 or 3. And not even get into checking 3 and 4

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  The logic was obviously flawed as well. Fortunately Gordon's method below should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is more efficient, but this is definitely easier to write and read:

```
SELECT *,
       DATEDIFF(day, StatusDate1, 
                COALESCE(StatusDate2, StatusDate3, StatusDate4, GETDATE()
               ) as NewStatusDate1
```

I'm not sure why you would call an integer results a "new status date".  Are you sure that you don't want `DATEADD()`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for.  Something easier to write and read.  Thank you!

Comment: If I did it was totally by accident.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, be aware that datediff measures 'boundary crossings', not the length of the interval.

Take these two points in time:

23:59 on Jan 1st

00:01 on Jan 2nd

In this scenario, the period is two minutes long.

For your needs, should that be considered a day?

Datediff will return 1 (when you use dd or equivalent), because the day part of the 2nd date is one more than the 1st.

If your data types are more precise than simply date, and instead you wanted it rounded - e.g longer than twelve hours is considered a day - you'll need a slightly different approach (e.g. Diff the minutes, then divide to get days)

Answer (score 0):

Case will take the first true result.  The way you had it, you would never get to StatusDate4 or GetDate because StatusDate2 would always return in one of the first two tests (NOT NULL or NULL).

You can simplify your case statement using this:

```
CASE
    WHEN StatusDate2 IS NOT NULL THEN StatusDate2
    WHEN StatusDate3 IS NOT NULL THEN StatusDate3
    WHEN StatusDate4 IS NOT NULL THEN StatusDate4
    ELSE GETDATE()
END
```

Comment: Yes, this is another good example of simplifying the way I had done it in addition to my logic being off.  Thank you.